# Problem when transferring to a bigger SD card for my Raspberry PI 2

Tags: sd-card

I bought Raspberry PI 2 and installed some web services on it. I have a fully functional Pi 2 with a 8GB micro SD card. 8GB is not enough so I bought a 32 GB card in order to have more available space. I want to transfer everything from the old card to the new one. I followed instructions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/858/how-do-i-transfer-my-setup-between-sd-cards?lq=1). I have a Raspbian installed. In short, here is what I did:

I plugged the old SD card in my Linux laptop, unmounted both partition, and typed the following command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=./rpi-backup.img
```

The output is:

```
1881+1 enregistrements lus
1881+1 enregistrements écrits
7892631552 octets (7,9 GB) copiés, 399,078 s, 19,8 MB/s
```

I unplugged the card, plugged the new one, unmounted it, and typed the following command:

```
sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/mmcblk0 if=./rpi-backup.img
```

The output is:

```
1881+1 enregistrements lus
1881+1 enregistrements écrits
7892631552 octets (7,9 GB) copiés, 1315,9 s, 6,0 MB/s
```

I eventually plugged the new card in my Raspberry PI and booted it. Unfortunately, I cannot SSH to it because it never received any IP. I do not have any screen to plug one on the Raspberry. Any idea on what I missed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a new micro SD card and it is working. So the problem was probably due to an [incompatible device](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards)!

Answer (score 1):

> "it never received any IP. I do not have any screen"

In other words it actually might not be running properly at all.

The green led should flash twice evenly on boot, then perhaps flicker a bit after that.  If it flashes a greater number of times (probably repeatedly), this [indicates a problem](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern).

If never comes on at all, this would indicate the SD card is not properly inserted or the connector is broken -- but I do not think that is your problem.  **However** I've noticed my Pi 2 will do this sometimes with an HDMI cable plugged in, but cutting the power then unplugging the cable, putting it back in and restoring the power correct that...go figure, I guess the power system is a little overly sensitive.

If it comes on and stays on, this indicates the SD card is not formatted properly.

You've already said you can mount and examine the first partition, so evidently it is partitioned well enough for that.  You could double check the MBR as described in the last half of [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/rpi-b-will-not-boot-according-to-arch-linux-manual/28466#28466).

Comment: The 8 GB SD card already works on the Pi 2. I checked the 32 GB SD card content and there is a kernel7.img file. However, inside the config.txt file, there is no `kernel=` line. Should I add one? At a specific place in the file?

Comment: If it's not there I think the right choice is made (but you could try anyway).  Sorry I mistook the part about the 8GB card being from the pi 2 originally.  Can you tell whether it boots properly?  The green LED should flash twice immediately, then flicker a bit.  If it flashes more than twice or not at all, something is wrong and the OS has not loaded properly.

Comment: It boots well with the 8GB SD card and I can SSH to it. With the 32GB card, the green LED stays green (never blink) so it seems that the SD card is not formatted properly. How is it possible with a `dd`? I checked the MBR and I have `mbr.test: x86 boot sector`. Is it a problem?

Comment: Have a look at [the list here](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#Working_.2F_Non-working_SD_cards).  There a few microSDHC 32GB cards anecdotally marked as not working on the pi.

Comment: OK... thanks! The problem is that I do not know the manufacturer of my SD card and nothing is written on the package... ^^