# HemantSinghdahiya

Tags: networking

Bought new Raspberry Pi 2B
Formatted microSD card
Raspbian burnt using disk imager software.Placed card in Pi.
Powered on.
Red LED and Green LED glow permanantly.
Is it fine.
Tried to connect it to laptop using ethernet cable(purpose was to see R pi headless on my laptop screen.. at laptop shows Network unplugged . Does not show ip address in ip scanner.

What could be likely problem??

Power adaptor is 5 V 700mA

Comment: You should edit your post to add a descriptive title instead of your name.

Comment: Red and green on constantly is what the 2 does with no SD card in.  Either you did not insert it properly, or it simply does not like the card -- see also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28571/5538 There are a few other reports of this here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way the Pi is designed to work. It assumes a network with a DHCP server. In this way it is no different to any other computer system. You could assign a static IP address, but you should refine your question and determine what you are trying to achieve.