# Raspbian SD card boots up Raspberry Pi model A, but not model B+ or Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, boot

I can create a Raspbian SD card with windowsimager, and dd that boots great on Raspberry Pi model A, but on models B+ and Raspberry Pi 2 I just get a green light. What I'm asking for is a list of possible reasons so I can research it myself and create more SD cards in the future?

Comment: Are you using the official image file? Is it the exact same card you plug into the different boards?

Answer (score 2):

> on models b+ and pi 2 i just get a green light.

That's what will happen if you turn it on with no SD card, and various people have described this problem here with cards that simply will not boot, e.g.:

- [Problem when transferring to a bigger SD card for my Raspberry PI 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/problem-when-transferring-to-a-bigger-sd-card-for-my-raspberry-pi-2#comment36296_28527) -> Notice the accepted answer was to replace the SD card.
- [Raspberry Pi 2 - Are 64GB UHS-I Class 1 SDXC cards supported?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28571/5538) -> The accepted answer has to do with "SD Card Formatter" improperly formatting that card due to a particular characteristic (size).

If you have used this card with any image on the B+ and 2 and it has worked, obviously that's not the problem, but if this card has never worked on either of them regardless of what image is on it, then they just will not accept the card.