# Raspberry Pi B+ dead on arrival

Tags: hardware

I got a new Raspberry Pi a couple days ago. When I connected the power supply the green ACT LED lit up but the PWR did not. I have not been able to get anything to appear on the HDMI monitor. I have tried 3 HDMI cables on 2 TVs as well as 3 different power supplies. With one power supply, the PWR LED will flicker once when I insert the USB cable into the Pi, but that is all. The green LED glows constantly.

Did I get a bad board? Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Given the information you have given I'd say the most likely scenario is you have not inserted a correctly written SD card.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the red Power light is not coming on, or steady, suggests you may indeed have a faulty board. I've powered the PI2 without an sdcard, with a faulty sdcard, with an sdcard that does not have RPI firmware on it, and in all cases the power light is steady

So, either

- all your PSU's are too weak; or
- if you're using the same USB cable each time, it is faulty; or
- faulty Pi

Answer (score 2):

A green ACT light staying on is what the + and 2 models will do if you power them up with no SD card, or the equivalent, an SD card which is not recognized as such by the hardware. We do occasionally get reports of this here; sometimes it seems to be a particular make and model of card and using a different one works.  It is also possible if the card is incorrectly formatted (e.g., does not have an [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)).

There are several examples linked in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/30253/5538) to a very similar question.

Comment: I have tried using two different SD cards. One came in the kit with my Pi and the other I set up using a downloaded NOOBS setup from the Pi foundation's website. I will try to reformat the card that came wiht the Pi and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and dicovered that it was the sd card which didn't have noobs installed on it try buying a pre installed noobs card it worked fine after I got one